# Issue with NavBar link moving to next line

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my navigation bar. I have five links on my navbar: Home, Size, Type, Resources, Help, all have dropdown content and subdropdown content except for "Home". Adding "Home" to the navigation bar seems to be pushing down "Help" to the next line. Does anyone have any input on how I can fix this? I have included my html and css.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0062ab;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: #0062ab;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.navbar li:hover>a {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(6, 66, 135);
}

.dropdown {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #0062ab;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 198);
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar li a {
  float: none;
  color: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(6, 66, 135);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover>.dropdown-subcontent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  min-width: 160 px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-top: -25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="sites/Home.aspx">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="location.href='http://mywebsite.com/sites/size.aspx'" type="button">Size</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style=left:13.5%;>
      <a href="/sites/MasterSpace.aspx">Master Suite</a>
      <li><a href="/sites/MasterSpace.aspx">Guest Suite</a>
        <div class="dropdown-subcontent">
          <a href="/sites/Space1.aspx">Space1</a>
          <a href="/sites/Space2.aspx">Space2</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="location.href='http://mywebsite.com/sites/type.aspx'" type="button">Type</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style=left:13.5%;>
      <a href="/sites/MultiFamily.aspx">Multi Family</a>
      <li><a href="/sites/SingleFamily.aspx">Single Family</a>
        <div class="dropdown-subcontent">
          <a href="/sites/Type1.aspx">Space1</a>
          <a href="/sites/Type2.aspx">Space2</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="location.href='http://mywebsite.com/sites/resources.aspx'" type="button">Resources</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style=left:13.5%;>
      <a href="/sites/Form1.aspx>Form 1</a>
                       <a href=" /sites/Form2.aspx ">Form 2</a>                           
                   
                 </div>
               </div>

<div class="dropdown ">
             <button class="dropbtn " onclick="location.href='http://mywebsite.com/sites/help.aspx' " type="button ">Resources</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content " style=left:13.5%;>
                       <a href="/sites/Faq.aspx>FAQ</a>
      <a href="/sites/contact.aspx">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNodE.jpg)

Comment: Heads up-- there is an unmatched open quote in your markup: `<a href="/sites/Form1.aspx>Form 1</a>`

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS, add this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/sh8wb3rg/14)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Changing the width to max-width: 325px; worked perfectly!